# Как отредактировать html код лендинга, написанного с использованием Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

Как отредактировать html код лендинга, написанного с использованием Symfony?
Ни разу с ним не работал.

Comment: Вам нужно найти twig-шаблон и отредактировать его. Он наверняка валяется с расширением .twig, а синтаксис у него [очень простой](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Comment: Спасибо. Буду искать

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435285/#comment453272_435285):

Вам нужно найти twig-шаблон и отредактировать его. Это наверняка файл с суффиксом `.twig`, а синтаксис у него [очень простой](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).